# phpmyadmin gives 500 error - possible memory issue

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've got a major issue with PHPMyAdmin since a recent update. If I try to access any PHP files in the phpmyadmin (/usr/share/phpmyadmin) directory I get a 500 error. This even happens if I simply create a

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

file to display current PHP info in the same directory.

I don't have this issue in other directories on my server. MySQL is working fine, and I can create and modify tables manually. WordPress sites on my server relying on MySQL work fine.

I did notice I was getting

> Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7040 bytes) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php on line 141

However, this doesn't happen constantly and the 500 error happens regardless. I've checked the php.ini files for all types (CGI, CLI, apache2) and all have a 256MB memory limit which seems ample. I tried increasing it to 512MB and restarting apache2 but to no avail.

This only seems to have happened since a recent update about 2 months ago.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Other software on my server such as roundcube webmail, WordPress and others work absolutely fine and do not present errors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE** As a workaround I've installed a seperate copy of PHPMyAdmin in a different area (without touching the Debian installed version). This works fine so I'm cosidering it a workaround for now. There must be some sort of PHP configuration issue that is denying access to the directory or not allocating any memory at all for one reason or another. Solution not yet determined.

Comment: What exactly did you update? Does it happen at all times or when you're doing heavy queries?

Comment: And have you looked at **line 141** in the index.php file? Just to get some sort of clue as to what might be going on at that point in the script

Comment: @Andrius it was a phpmyadmin update together with other php5 updates issued through apt. (Debian 8, PHP 5.6.14, ISPConfig 3.0.5.4p8). It happens at all times - I can't even log in to PHPMyAdmin at this point (all pages give 500 error).

Comment: What do you mean 'other php5 updates'? What version did you update from? What PHPMyAdmin version are you at?

Comment: @RiggsFolly line 141 is a php echo 
      echo '<h2>' . __('General Settings') . '</h2>';
within an if statement for if PHPMyAdmin is on a demo server.

Comment: @Andrius according to my dpkg log it is currently running version 4.2.12 which does seem somewhat outdated. It has only been updated via Debian upgrades (it was not manually installed). Perhaps I should try manually installing it in a seperate directory?

Comment: Indeed. If everything is working apart from PHPMyAdmin, just update it again, properly this time :)

Comment: @Andrius just installed it manually elsewhere and it works fine. Must be some sort of config issue in my PHP setup. Oh well, workaround found for now! Thanks for your help.